# Error when assigning the Storage Admin IAM role to my service account

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, devops

I have the following script ( I've change the AZURE_PIPELINES_PUBLISHER ):

> ```
> AZURE_PIPELINES_PUBLISHER=azure-pipelines-publisher@$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com
>
> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT \
>     --member serviceAccount:$AZURE_PIPELINES_PUBLISHER \
>     --role roles/storage.admin
> ```

I write this script on 'Arguments' field of the Docker push task, in Azure DevOps, when i run the build, this task shows the following error:

> unknown flag: --member

I get the script from the [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creating-cicd-pipeline-vsts-kubernetes-engine#command-line_1).

What's wrong in the script?

Comment: `--member` is a flag of the `gcloud` command. So the docker task which probably passes the arguments to a docker client somewhere won't know what `--member` means.
Do you know what the CMD of the image you are using is?

Answer (score 1):

From the tutorial, `gcloud` command should run in the Cloud Shell. It's not 'Arguments' of the Docker push task. It's supposed creating a Google Cloud service account in your production project and assign the role before you configure Azure Pipelines to build and publish a container image.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?